# Event.target doesn't work under Locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

controller.js

```
selectedValue: function(component, event, helper) {
    let componentDiv = event.target;
    let searchString = document.createRange();
}
```

component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.searchAccounts}" var="act">                           
<div aura:id="accountSearchdiv" class="slds-input" onclick="{!c.selectedValue}"
    onmouseover="{!c.highlightSelectedValue}" onmouseout="{!c.removeHighlightedValue}"
    data-value="{!act.Id}">{!act.Name}
</div> </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Please also post the component part.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: In the component Part, what we are doing is calling a method when user selects a name and I have put that in a division inside Aura Iteration

Comment: I'm not geting any errors, but it works fine in api version 39. I'm not getting any value in componentDiv in Api versions above 40

Comment: Please share your component code. It seems that the jump from 39 to 40 is likely the issue here and we may be able to help your make changes so that this works with Locker Service. (The current API version is 50, BTW, so when making the jump you may as well get it working with the most recent version)

Comment: Added component code